# Can I export c++ template class to C and therefore to python with ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, c

For a non template class I would write something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

But I don't know what should I do if my class is a template class.

I've tried something like that and it's not working.

```
extern "C" {
    Demodulator<double>* Foo_new_double(){ return new Demodulator<double>(); }
    Demodulator<float>* Foo_new_float(){ return new Demodulator<float>(); }
    void demodulateDoubleMatrix(Demodulator<double>* demodulator, double * input, int rows, int columns){ demodulator->demodulateMatrixPy(input, rows, columns) }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have C++ in `extern "C"`

Comment: In the link that I've gaved they using new operator in extern C. That's C++ right? So either they wrong or you, right?

Comment: @user1685095 but you have C++ in function declaration - templates. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877705/why-cant-templates-be-within-extern-c-blocks

Comment: Let me rephrase that, the prototypes in `extern "C"` should be C.  You can have whatever inside your functions but C has no idea what a template is.

Comment: @user1685095 If you must use C++ with Python you should go with Boost.Python or SWIG

Comment: I appreciate your answers, but can you give me an answer to my question? If I have a template class, that I need to export to C, what should I do?

Comment: @user1685095 Then you need to manually write a C-wrappers yourself for each class and function you export.

Comment: can you elaborate on that? What would this C-wrapper should be like?

Comment: @user1685095 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694515/c-wrapper-for-c-how-to-deal-with-c-templates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54651/discussion-between-user1685095-and-anycorn).

Comment: Yes you can decorate C++ code with `extern "C"`. This has the effect that function don't get name-mangled and that you can then find them via `dlsym()`. Further, it is formally required for functions that you want to pass to `pthread_create()`, although in practice I'm not aware of a case where that fails.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Your question contradicts the code partially, so I'm ignoring the code for now.

C++ templates are an elaborated macro mechanism that gets resolved at **compile time**. In other words, the binary only contains the code from template instantiations (which is what you get when you apply parameters, typically types, to the the template), and those are all that you can export from a binary to other languages. Exporting them is like exporting any regular type, see for example `std::string`.

Since the templates themselves don't survive compilation, there is no way that you can export them from a binary, not to C, not to Python, not even to C++! For the latter, you can provide the templates themselves though, but that doesn't include them in a binary.

Two assumptions:

- Exporting/importing works via binaries. Of course, you could write an import that parses C++.
- C++ specifies (or specified?) export templates, but as far as I know, this isn't really implemented in the wild, so I left that option out.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ language started as a *superset* of C: That is, it contains new keywords, syntax and capabilities that C does not provide. C does not have the concept of a `class`, has no concept of a member function and does not support the concept of access restrictions. C also does not support inheritance. The really big difference, however, is templates. C has macros, and that's it.

Therefore no, you can't directly expose C++ code to C in any fashion, you will have to use C-style code in your C++ to expose the C++ layer.

```
 template<T> T foo(T i) { /* ... */ }
 extern "C" int fooInt(int i) { return foo(i); }
```

However C++ was originally basically a C code generator, and C++ can still interop (one way) with the C ABI: member functions are actually implemented by turning `this->function(int arg);` into `ThisClass0int1(this, arg);` or something like that. In theory, you could write something to do this to your code, perhaps leveraging clang.

But that's a non-trivial task, something that's already well-tackled by SWIG, Boost::Python and Cython.

The problem with templates, however, is that the compiler ignores them until you "instantiate" (use) them. std::vector<> is not a concrete thing until you specify `std::vector<int>` or something. And now the only concrete implementation of that is `std::vector<int>`. Until you've specified it somewhere, `std::vector<string>` doesn't exist in your binary.

You probably want to start by looking at something like this http://kos.gd/2013/01/5-ways-to-use-python-with-native-code/, select a tool, e.g. SWIG, and then start building an interface to expose what you want/need to C. This is a lot less work than building the wrappers yourself. Depending which tool you use, it may be as simple as writing a line saying `using std::vector<int>` or `typedef std::vector<int> IntVector` or something.

---- EDIT ----

The problem with a *template class* is that you are creating an entire type that C can't understand, consider:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    T a;
    int b;
    T c;
public:
    Foo(T a_) : a(a_) {}
    void DoThing();
    T GetA() { return a; }
    int GetB() { return b; }
    T GetC() { return c; }
};
```

The C language doesn't support the `class` keyword, never mind understand that members a, b and c are private, or what a constructor is, and C doesn't understand member functions.

Again it doesn't understand templates so you'll need to do what C++ does automatically and generate an instantiation, by hand:

```
struct FooDouble {
    double a;
    int b;
    double c;
};
```

Except, all of those variables are private. So do you really want to be exposing them? If not, you probably just need to typedef "FooDouble" to something the same size as Foo and make a macro to do that.

Then you need to write replacements for the member functions. C doesn't understand constructors, so you will need to write a

```
extern "C" FooDouble* FooDouble_construct(double a);

FooDouble* FooDouble_construct(double a) {
    Foo* foo = new Foo(a);
    return reinterept_cast<FooDouble*>(foo);
}
```

and a destructor

```
extern "C" void FooDouble_destruct(FooDouble* foo);

void FooDouble_destruct(FooDouble* foo) {
    delete reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(foo);
}
```

and a similar pass-thru for the accessors.

Comment: Well, I need to export only one class, so I guess the cost of dugging in SWIG is more than a beneficial.

I also understand that in the binary would be only those functions, that's called from somewhere in the code. So for every type that's used would be one function fooInt, fooDouble or something like that.

What I don't understand is can I expose c++ template class to C with some exact type.

Like extern "C" Foo * FooInt_new(new Foo<int>()). And why is this not working? I gave it the type right? Why can't it compile this class with this type?

Comment: Because C doesn't support templates. When you say `extern "C" ...` you are making a promise to the compiler that everything in the elipsis is going to be `C` code and, again, C doesn't have templates.

Comment: Look at the example code fragment I included above - you can do that, although it's probably better to separate the implementation from the extern.

Comment: Ok, I got that... Well... Can someone show how to these "manual wrappers"? Is that really that hard? I really think that to export one class shouldn't be that hard...

Comment: The "fooInt" function above is an example. As long as the function fingerprint is pure C, you're good, you'll just have to separate the function body. I'll edit my answer real quick.

Comment: kfsone, I see you snippet. But there is template function in it. Not template class. How to do that with class? I can't instantiate new class in every call of the function.

Comment: Class is where it is worth doing Swig, because C fundamentally can't understand the type. SWIG/Boost::Python will generate a custom structure that mirrors the instantiation of `Demodulator<double>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54659/discussion-between-user1685095-and-kfsone).