# Error with Dynamic Dll function loading

Tags: c++

I am trying to export dlls and load it dynamically during runtime. dumpbin export output for the constructor for the class gives me the below output.

1    0 000111B8 ??4myclass@nmspace@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z = @ILT+435(??4myclass@nmspace@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z)

typedef void (WINAPI * PCTOR) ();

I am trying to get the virtual address using below two lines.
PCTOR pCtor = (PCTOR)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, (LPCSTR)DWORD(1));
PCTOR pCtor = (PCTOR)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "??4myclass@nmspace@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z");

Then I call the constructor with the below line 
pCtor ();

When I use the DWORD(1) 
 pCtor value  - **nmspace::myclass::operator=(class nmspace::myclass const &)**

pCtor() works fine.

But for the second line using the actual value for the exported function
pCtor value - **nmspace::myclass::myclass(void)**

pCtor() gives me **ESP was not properly saved...** error.

Can I get some help on what is the problem in this case.

Comment: Write C wrapper for C++ library, and load dynamically this C wrapper. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691035/c-wrapper-for-c In this answer replace SomeObj* with void* in C wrapper functions.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke methods from a C++ class using C code? There are more things to consider...why don't you simply export classes then? If you need a C interface then embed it where classes reside.

Comment: I have an 3rd Party c++ library which is used in my application. I want to load dlls only when my application needs it.So, I tried to use help from  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9405/Using-classes-exported-from-a-DLL-using-LoadLibrar) ..I tried to use the getProcaddress as mentioned in my question. It works fine with the syntax using DWORD.   But I want to understand the basic difference between the two function pointers returned in both cases.