# How to write a gRPC client/server in C?

Tags: c, grpc

I have a program written in C and want to include gRPC in it. However, the API for gRPC is written in C++.

I've looked here and got the foo_client and foo_server working. 
https://github.com/Juniper/grpc-c/tree/master/examples

However, the C client is not compatible with my gRPC C++ server. They will not talk to each other. I believe it is because I am using the lates gRPC which uses protocbuf version 3.2.0. And Juniper's grpc-c is using an older version of gRPC that uses protocbuf version 3.0.0.

So the Juniper version in C doesn't seem to work with the new gRPC. I know the gRPC low level C API is supposed to be here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/grpc.h 
But I'm having difficulty implementing it. Can anyone help me make sense of it?

I haven't programmed in C in awhile so I'm a little rusty.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the gRPC core library directly, then you will need to perform your own serialization, and deal with low level operations documented in  https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h.

If you have any specific questions, we will be happy to help, but if this is just a one-time thing it might be easier to just solve the version incompatibility problem, or maybe simply wrap the C++ implementation with a C interface.

Comment: Do you know of any code examples for C wrapper for C++ implementation ?

Comment: @Manohar `extern C {}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691035/c-wrapper-for-c?

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do this in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this:

1. Call gRPC's CPP functions from your C code: To do so, create a C API to expose the features of your C++ code. Write C++ functions marked with extern "C" and design a pure C API that encapsulates the C++ library. More details here: [How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c) and here: [Mixing C and Cpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp)
2. Use unofficial gRPC libraries for C: I have seen [juniper-grpc-c (Github)](https://github.com/juniper/grpc-c) mentioned in a few different places.
3. Use a HTTP/2 C Library: gRPC builds on top of HTTP2, so with a library like https://nghttp2.org/, you could have C bindings for gRPC.
4. Use [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/): Thrift is a lightweight, language-independent software stack for point-to-point RPC implementation which has a C-client. If replacing gRPC is an option, you can try this out.