# C library for gRPC

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have not found support of the C language on grpc.io. Are there any "unofficial" libraries supporting gRPC in C?

My whole project is in C. I'm seeing a few options:

- rewrite in C++ (inefficient, just to support gRPC)
- write module talking gRPC in C++ and mix with C (I guess this is doable, but quite ugly?)
- find a C library implementing gRPC API etc.
- write my own using the core library from grpc.io (have no idea, how difficult it's going to be)

Answer (score 1):

Unoffical library:

- [github.com/juniper/grpc-c](https://github.com/juniper/grpc-c) "C implementation of gRPC layered on top of core library"

Related:

- [github.com/nanopb/nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb) "Nanopb is a small code-size Protocol Buffers implementation in ansi C. It is especially suitable for use in microcontrollers, but fits any memory restricted system."
- [github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c) "Protocol Buffers implementation in C"
- former discussion of the topic: [stackoverflow.com/a/50955104/18980756](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50955104/18980756)